# Writing PHP code in wordpress pages using Helloinfinity PHP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

**I am using a plugin named "Helloinfinity PHP" for inserting php codes in Wordpress pages, but it is not working in this case... If anyone could please help me..
The code using Helloinfinity PHP plugin is**

```
<td style="width:200px; align:center;"> 
<select style="width:90%; text-align:center;"  name="s_roll_year" id="s_roll_year">
    <option value="0">Crores.</option>
[hi_php]
      for($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++)
      {
[/hi_php]
    <option value="[hi_php] echo $i; [/hi_php]">[hi_php] echo $i; [/hi_php]</option>
[hi_php]
      }
[/hi_php]

</select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that all statements are evaluated separately. Meaning, you can't separate statements that depend on each other. Instead, do something like:

```
[hi_php]
    for($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++)
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
    }
[/hi_php]
```

Comment: Great! Please select my answer as correct, to close this question.